# ImmutableJS: how to convert to JSON an opaque variable

Tags: immutable.js

I have an opaque variable on my hand. I know it can be an object, a primitive value, an immutable, or an object whose values can be immutables.

I need to convert deeply this object to json for logging.

The following does not work, because it does not cover the case where the immutables are nested inside a real json object:

```
 const json = isImmutable(obj)
    ? obj.toJS()
    : obj
```

Is there a simple way to convert my opaque structure to json?

I know nesting immutables in non immutables may not be such a good idea. Still looking for a simple solution that does not involve large refactorings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
console.log(Immutable.fromJS(obj).toJS());
```

Here, first step is to convert the entire "obj" to immutable using fromJS(). Doing so will make all the nested plain objects and arrays immutable. Final step is to convert the entire "obj' to plainJS by using toJS(). End result is plainJS "obj"

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Comment: Please add all explanation to the answer itself, not to the comment section